# Call C# from unmanaged Excel Addin (XLL)

Tags: c++, excel-interop, xll

I am trying to call into C# dll from regular C++ Excel Addin (not Excel DNA)
I added additional C++ file to the project and enabled CLI support on it. 
The code executes fine. When I close Excel it crashes. What might be the reason ?

Stack trace

```
MSO.DLL!6b4d21a6() 
[Frames below may be incorrect and/or missing, no symbols loaded for MSO.DLL]
MSO.DLL!6b43d95b() 
EXCEL.EXE!0140fcfe() 
msvcr100.dll!@_EH4_CallFilterFunc@8()  + 0x12 bytes
msvcr100.dll!__except_handler4_common()  + 0x86 bytes
EXCEL.EXE!022cead6() 
ntdll.dll!ExecuteHandler2@20()  + 0x26 bytes
ntdll.dll!ExecuteHandler@20()  + 0x24 bytes
ntdll.dll!_KiUserExceptionDispatcher@8()  + 0xf bytes
EXCEL.EXE!01084d52() 
EXCEL.EXE!01e40e70()
```

Comment: what do you do with your c# code ? do you call excel interop ?

Comment: No interop. Just some calculation.

Comment: I even removed referenced C# dlls altogether. The moment I add a call to a function implemented in managed C++ the crash occurs. It seems it happens because of some issue with CRT

Comment: @SparcU: that stack trace shows an exception being handled, so it doesn't tell us the real root cause. Have you tried running in debug from inside Visual Studio, with Excel.exe as the launch command for your XLL? Just before you shut down Excel switch on first chance exceptions in the debug settings.